# How to exit tail -f and resume script

Tags: linux, bash, tail

I have a simple script, that sets up logging, runs `tail -f` on the log file and then, after I exit `tail`, performs some cleanup. Basically something like this

```
echo 'monitoring started'
tail -f /var/log/some.log
echo 'never gets here'
```

Problem is, exiting `tail` by Ctrl+C breaks the script execution too, so cleanup is not called. Is there a way to 'properly' exit `tail` and resume script call? I found a few solutions based on saving PID and killing it by timeout, but that's not what I want here, I may need the monitoring for a few minutes or few hours, so I'd like to have a manual switch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
echo "monitoring started"
tail -f /var/log/some.log & #execute tail in background
read -sn 1 #wait for user input
kill %1 #kill the first background progress, i.e. tail
echo "Is reached"
```